# neo4j adding a return changes the amount of nodes matched

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to perform a search to get some basic figures.

```
MATCH(l:letter)-[:RECIPIENT]-(a:address{country: "England"})
RETURN a
```

**Result** = `56`

**Note**

When a letter is processed, the address is added if it is not already on the database, if it already exists, a relationship is created to the existing node.
Therefore, no address should exist here that does not connect to a `letter` node, although the `relationship` could be `sender` rather than `recipient`.

If I add a count for letters, I get a different address count.

```
MATCH(l:letter)-[:RECIPIENT]-(a:address{country: "England"})
RETURN a, l
```

**Result** - a = 2, l = 298

Likewise, if I return only letters, I get different figure again.

```
MATCH(l:letter)-[:RECIPIENT]-(a:address{country: "England"})
RETURN l
```

**Result** - l = 300

What am I missing?

I thought that the `MATCH` defines the query, and the `RETURN` is just choosing which parts of the information to display, how does `RETURN` alter the matched data?

Comment: what do you mean by result? For example in the second query... both a and l will be present in the same amount of rows... are you looking at distinct number of nodes or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the total number of nodes that are letters, you need to add DISTINCT.

```
MATCH(l:letter)-[:RECIPIENT]-(a:address{country: "England"})
RETURN count(distinct l) as numLetterNodes
```

```
MATCH(l:letter)-[:RECIPIENT]-(a:address{country: "England"})
RETURN count(distinct a) as numAddressNodes
```

When you start combining the letters and addresses in your results you will end up with aggregates per row.

```
MATCH(l:letter)-[:RECIPIENT]-(a:address{country: "England"})
RETURN DISTINCT a.id, count(l) as lettersPerAddress
```

```
MATCH(l:letter)-[:RECIPIENT]-(a:address{country: "England"})
RETURN DISTINCT l.id, count(a) as addressesPerLetter
```

Comment: Yes, this is it! Use `DISTINCT` inside the `COUNT` brackets